# more than one issue--jquery mostly works in Chrome but not IE or Firefox, also need help separating links, and opening windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

So here is my problem. I have a list of checkboxes.  When clicked and submitted it is to generate a list from the selected checkboxes that are links to resources.  The links are to open in a new window.

I am still working out the bugs but when I test it in Chrome it mostly works (as in it generates my new list and creates at least one link) when I test it in IE or firefox it doesn't appear to work at all.  I have done an alert test to make sure I have jquery/javascript enabled.

Another problem other than browser issues I am having is that when my list is generated from the checkbox clicks, my new list is to be links.  What ends up happening is that it is one big link instead of seperate links.  Not too sure how to fix that.

Then I need each link to open in a new window.  I think once I figure these other details out I am sure I can figure this out.  I am just getting rather frustrated.  I have included my code.  Maybe someone can help me figure out what the heck I am doing wrong!!!

Thanks for your help!

Kind Regards,
KMS

```js
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        outputResources();
 $("#reset").click(function(){
        location.reload();
    });
 });
});

 
   

function outputResources(){
 
 
 var resourceArray=[];
 $(".resource:checked").each(function(){
  resourceArray.push($(this).val());
 });
 
 //urls
 var urlsArray=[];
 $(".resource:checked").each(function(){
  urlsArray.push($(this).attr("href"));
 });
 
 var links;
 links=urlsArray;
  
 var results;
 results=resourceArray;
 
 var output ="You have selected:<li><a class='rLinks' href='"+links+"'>"+results+"</a></li>";
 
 
 if(results.length>0){
  $("#show").attr("disabled",true); 
  $("#resourceResults").html(output);
  displayResults();
 }else{
  $("#show").attr("disabled",false);
  alert("Please select one or more resources to continue");
  
 }
 
}


//resource used: http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_hide_show.asp
function displayResults(){
 $("#resourceResults").show(2000).delay("slow").fadeIn();
 
 
 $("#cList").hide("slow").fadeOut(2000);
 $("#reset").show(2000).delay("slow").fadeIn();
}

$("a.rLinks").click(function(){
 window.open();
 return false; 
});
 

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Tell us how we can help you.  </p>
<section id="checklist">
<h3>I would like to know more about the following resources:</h3>
<form id="cList">
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource1" href="https://www.google.com">resource1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource2" href="https://www.google.com">resource2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource3" href="https://www.google.com">resource3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource4" href="https://www.google.com">resource4<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource5" href="https://www.google.com">resource5<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource6" href="https://www.google.com">resource6<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="resource" value="resource7" href="https://www.google.com">resource7<br>

<button id="show"> Show Me the Resources</button>

</form>

<div id="resourceResults">
</div>
<button id="reset"> Reset</button>
</section>
```

Comment: figured out my problems!

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the best way to open a link in a new tab, but it will work: `$('< a >').attr('target', '_blank').attr('href', your_link).click()'. It still creates a new anchor and clicks on it.